# Selecting similar objects by modifiers

Tags: scripting, modifiers, selection-tools

I have a collection of objects, each with different modifiers, and I want to select only the objects that have a bevel modifier in their modifier stack, is there a way to do that? Maybe a script of sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import bpy


for eachObject in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    for eachModifier in eachObject.modifiers:
        if eachModifier.type == "BEVEL":
            eachObject.select_set(True)
```